# Lumen: How to make Auth login for user using middleware?

Tags: php, authentication, middleware, lumen, lumen-5.2

I'm trying to pass a username and password from a form into a controller, check if that user exists (users database table), and then redirect to an authenticated page where only users that are logged in can see their username.

In my `routes.php`:

```
$app->post('/', ['uses' => 'AuthenticationController@login']);

$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ($app) {
    $app->post('/tickets', ['uses' => 'TicketsController@getTickets']);
});
```

Then my `AuthenticationController.php` login function:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only(['username','password']);

    $user = App\User::find($credentials);

    if ($user) {
        // I'm assuming you do a redirect() here but am unsure how with Auth
    } else {
        return 'not logged in';
    }
}
```

At this point, I don't know what I need to put into my `getTickets` function in my TicketsController.php.

Anyone that knows how to go about doing this, please throw me a bone as to how to proceed.

Ultimately, it'll be great to have the `tickets.blade.php` view to have `{{ user->username }}` and to display the username of who's logged in. If the user doesn't log in and visits this view, nothing displays because they're not authenticated.

**EDIT:** Currently, I'm getting this error:

> FatalErrorException in AuthenticationController.php: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\App\User' not found

I do have both of these lines included in my `AuthenticationController.php` before all functions begin:

```
use App\User;
use Auth;
```

Maybe it's the way I'm passing my `$credentials` into the find function, but that doesn't solve the Authentication side of things.

Comment: First of all the error you have posted is a namespace issue. Remove `App\User` in the find method and just have `User`. Secondly, this looks like Laravel authentication and I'm pretty sure this is not really how Lumen authentication is supposed to work. see [docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

Comment: @tam I see what you mean, but the docs you mentioned use Auth in association with an API key, which in my case, I don't need. Only user creds to authenticate user through middleware.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: @PradeepSapkota Sadly, still no - but I implore others to start a bounty if anyone's interested :)

Comment: If you are using authentication to guard the `getTickets` I suggest you use OAauth2 . Here is a framework https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel